# String Underline modification in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the underlining the textfield used for showing it as the link.

I am using the following code:

```
     final String Email1 = new String("http://myURL/");
                Email.setText("W : "+Email1);
                Email.setPaintFlags(Email.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

I am getting the output as below :

[image]

I am getting the underline for **W:** also... **Please help with the code to omit the underline to W:**

Comment: means you want to underline the TextView, right?

Comment: yes... Here Textview is Email. But i am getting the attached image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried???

```
Html.fromHtml("W:"+"<u>" +Email1+ "</u>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two TextViews alongside each other.  One containing the "W : ", the other with the email address.